# Preventing Scheduled Agent from executing when modified

Tags: vba, scripting, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a scheduled agent that runs Weekly at one particular time on a target of All new & modified documents.

If I modify this agent, even if I only save it, it runs again.

If I remember correctly from long long ago, I have to add code such as this:

```
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
  Dim agent As NotesAgent

  Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

  Set agent = db.GetAgent("myAgent")

If agent.HasRunSinceModified = False
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Am I remembering correctly? And I always wondered, why would an agent fire off after being modified? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Isn't it something like If agent.Run = 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My response corresponds to your title: Preventing Scheduled Agent from executing when modified.

The solution is to move all your code to a script library, and never change the agent (since no need of it).

When you modify your code in the script library the agent is not fired.

You can also read [Notes Designer runs agent after saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417967/notes-designer-runs-agent-after-saving) which suggest (I didn't test) Amgr_SkipPriorDailyScheduledRuns=1